# Add paper-button and icons to Paper-card header

Tags: polymer, material-design, polymer-1.0

At the moment the paper-card element has an attribute *heading* that I can use to setup the header of the card as following:

```
<paper-card heading="my header">
   <div class="card-content>
      <span>My body</span>
   </div>
</paper-card>
```

I need to add to the right of the header area two *paper-icon-button* so that I can obtain the following result:

[image]

Is this possible in Polymer 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are examples https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-card
Use class content-card and don't use header attribute in paper-card element

```
<paper-card>
   <paper-icon-item class="card-header">
       <iron-icon class="avatar" item-icon src="masters-icon.ico"></iron-icon>
       <paper-item-body two-line>
           <div>My title</div>
           <div secondary>my secondary text</div>
       </paper-item-body>
   </paper-icon-item>
   <iron-image sizing="cover" src="{{url}}"></iron-image>
   <div class="card-content">
       <p>Some other text</p>
   </div>
</paper-card>
```

Comment: I know these examples and none of them is using buttons inside the header.

Comment: I hope thet example is usefull. If no, I'll explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example on the components page here https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-card under the section "Paper-cards can contain advanced content"

Comment: These examples do not use custom header, but custom content

Comment: And where is the problem with that?

Comment: My question was to know if the header is customizable, I know how to add a paper toolbar into a paper element ;-)

Comment: But why do you want to have the buttons as a header of the paper-card? It doesn't add any kind of special styling so I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: if you read the material design guidelines you can have a toolbar inside a card so i though that the element paper-based had it. That's it